# Must declare the scalar variable?

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
ALTER PROCEDURE selectedrfp
@from datetime,
@to datetime,
@bdename varchar(max),
@status int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @query varchar(max)
set @query='
SELECT RS.[RFP_ICode]
      ,RS.[Client_ICode]
      ,RS.[Client_Name]
      ,RS.[Project_Title]
      ,RS.[Client_Country]
      ,RS.[RFP_Technology]
      ,RS.[RFP_Received_Date] 
      ,RS.[Cgvak_Comh_WishList]
        FROM dbo.Cgvak_RFP_Status AS RS
           INNER JOIN CGVAK_RFP_Status_Master AS RSM
           ON RSM.[RFP_Status_Icode]=RS.[RFP_Status]
           INNER JOIN CGVAK_RFP_Users AS RU
           ON RU.[RFP_User_ICode]=RS.[BDE_Icode]
         WHERE RS.[Cgvak_Comh_WishList]=1 
           AND RS.[RFP_Received_Date] BETWEEN @from  AND @to
--           AND RS.[BDE_Name]=@bdename 
           AND RSM.[RFP_Status_ICode]=@status
           AND RU.[RFP_User_Type] IN(1,2,3)'
DECLARE @withoutbde varchar(max)
SET @withoutbde='ORDER BY RS.[RFP_Received_Date] DESC'
DECLARE @withbde varchar(max)
SET @withbde='AND RS.[BDE_Name]=@bdename ORDER BY RS.[RFP_Received_Date] DESC'
IF(@bdename='All')
EXEC (@query + @withoutbde )
ELSE IF(@bdename!='All') 
EXEC (@query + @withbde )
END

EXEC selectedrfp @from='2010/01/01',@to='2011/06/22',@bdename='chad',@status=4
```

Answer (score 3):

The local variables @bdename etc are not in scope in the dynamic SQL.

You should use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to parameterise them properly. Don't concatenate them.